# Is it possible for Base class to have an association to it's derived class?

Tags: c++, class

Is it possible/logically correct for Base class to have an association relationship to it's derived classes?
For example:

```
class First_Child;
class Second_Child;

class Base
{
private:
    First_Child** ppFirstChild;
protected:
    Second_Child** ppSecondChild;
}

class First_Child : public Base
{
    // I want First child to be able to access **ppSecondChild**
}

class Second_Child : public Base
{
   // I want Second child to NOT be able to access **ppFirstChild**
}
```

I found nothing on google related to this subject.
Please feel free to suggest other takeaways[my objective would be to be able to access those double pointers as mentioned in comments from child classes].

Comment: Look into [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp)) - but `First_Child` and `Second_Child` won't share a common base if you use it.

Comment: Looks like homework...Move everything under `private:` section. And make `First_Child` a `friend class`

Comment: Btw, why are you using _pointer-pointers_? Is there any reason why you are not using `std::vector`?

Comment: @malat Not a homework, but some personal practice, indeed. I had this idea and just wanted to know if it is logically correct or somehow accepted by vast majority, since I've found nothing on this subject. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Ted At work I use pointers a lot and I'm used to it. ```std::vector``` I used only once and same, in a practice problem.

Comment: "Is it possible" is a question faster answered by compiling than writing up a question. "Logically correct" depends on your overall design. Since the code matches your intent, what is the question for us?

Comment: If it's logically correct and good design depends on what the goal is. It's certainly _possible_ to do this. If you use raw pointers a lot at work you must be really comfortable with the rule of 3/5/0 and RAII. Is that correct? I can't imagine getting my code through a code review if I used raw pointers where `vector`s, or in some cases smart pointers, could be used.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not using ```vector``` is one of project(embedded one)'s restrictions. Nor dynamic allocation(so nothing to deallocate in destructor). Nor smart pointers. I work in C++03. But that's another topic. Anyway, you guys clarified things for me. I wanted to know if it is somehow accepted, if it is not a bad practice.Thank you!

Comment: "_Nor dynamic allocation(so nothing to deallocate in destructor)_" - I don't see how you can fulfill that. The code you've shown will require dynamic allocation some way or another.

Comment: My code, yes indeed.

Comment: @lukuss So, for your code, use `vector`s and/or smart pointers. I assume you are not working in C++03 in your own project?

Comment: No, no, I'm not using 03. All right, I'll use them. Thanks.